# Can we imply from this recent report that COVID-19 strain A might inoculate against strains B and C?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

Apparently 3 strains were identified and the first strain seemed to protect from the more dangerous second and third strains:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsCo8w67FhE

https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.04.08.20056929v1.full.pdf+html

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that idea from the paper. (I didn't look at the video). The paper is about where the NYC strains came from (seemingly mostly directly from Europe, but also from the rest of the US). I don't see immunity or antibodies discussed at all in the paper, so...

Comment: Per the video, as I understood it, beginning about a minute or so in, contracting the more benign A strain makes one resistant to the more dangerous B and C versions.

Comment: The paper says no such thing and you should really stop watching random youtube videos on such matters.

Comment: I watched the first 2 minutes of the video and I have no idea what she's basing her claims on. The paper she cites says nothing that supports her report.

Answer (score 3):

That paper analyses the origin of the strains observed in NYC (spoiler: most came from Europe). The paper doesn't discuss at all the "dangerousness" of the strains. One could have spread more simply because more travellers arrived to NYC from Europe than from Washington state (the 2nd most common source/strain) or any other locally favorable factors. (For example, two prior "failed" introductions were one from the Middle East and another one from Europe. The paper doesn't discuss why these didn't spread in NTC, e.g. whether it was effective quarantine of the person carrying them, or some other [lucky] reason.)

Also there's not discussion on immunity whatsoever in the paper, so drawing any conclusions from there as to antibodies for which strain protect against which [other] is completely unsupported by that paper.